# How to get 0 if no row found from sql query in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am getting blank value with this query from sql server

```
SELECT TOP 1 Amount from PaymentDetails WHERE Id = '5678'
```

it has no row,that is why its returning blank,So I want if no row then it should return 0

I already tried with COALESCE ,but its not working

how to solve this?

Comment: Why `TOP` with no `ORDER BY`? If there are multiple rows, are you happy with any arbitrary value? I *assume* you're setting this value to a scalar variable? if so, why not wrap the subquery in `ISNULL`, or handle the `NULL` value in your application?

Comment: Actually its for a single scalar variable.Can you please solve this sql.please

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the subquery in an `ISNULL`:

```
SELECT ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 Amount from PaymentDetails WHERE Id = '5678' ORDER BY ????),0) AS Amount;
```

Don't forget to add a column (or columns) to your `ORDER BY` as otherwise you will get inconsistent results when more than one row has the same value for `Id`. If `Id` is unique, however, then remove both the `TOP` and `ORDER BY` as they aren't needed.

You should never, however, use `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` unless you are "happy" with inconsistent results.

Comment: Had missed a left paranthesis, apoligies @Vidhya .

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting an arbitrary amount, so one method is aggregation:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(Amount), 0) 
FROM PaymentDetails
WHERE Id = '5678';
```

Note that if `id` is a number, then don't use single quotes for the comparison.

To be honest, I would expect `SUM()` to be more useful than an arbitrary value:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Amount), 0) 
FROM PaymentDetails
WHERE Id = '5678';
```